# How import a object or Class in Scala file from another Scala file?

Tags: scala, gatling, stress-testing

I have two Scala files and i need to import from second Scala file a class, but i dont know

In the first scala file i have a requests, and in especific request i want to call a object from second file in this object i have a authenticate request.

How i can import?

Sorry for my basic question, im new in Gatling, i need help :c

My first file has:

```
     class SearchCustomerClientNumber2 extends Simulation {

     val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("http://URL")
    .inferHtmlResources()
    .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("es-CL,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0")

       .exec(http("request_9")
        .get("/bei010Web/bei010/sp_MX/bei10.jsp")
        .headers(headers_0))
    .pause(1)
    .exec(http("request_10")
        .get("/bei010Web/Security?WSDL")
        .resources(http("request_11")
        .get("/bei010Web/Activities?WSDL")))
    .pause(4)

    //here i want to import a object from another scala file is 
     aauthenticate web service 
        .resources(http("request_13")
        .post("/bei010Web/Security")
        .headers(headers_13)
        .body(RawFileBody("SearchCustomerClientNumber2_0013_request.txt")),
```

My second Scala file:

```
      Class IC6SaaSRestUAT_Tuves extends Simulation {

val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("http://URL")  // PROD
    .inferHtmlResources()
    .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("es-CL,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0")


val csvFeeder = csv("Users.csv").circular // use a comma separator
    val headers_12 = Map(
    "Content-length" -> "1135",
    "Content-type" -> "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "SOAPAction" -> """""""")
val uri1 = "http://URL/bBBBBWeb/" 

print("*******")
print("*******")
print(csvFeeder)
object IC6SaaS {  //I want to import this object if is possible
    val ic = feed(csvFeeder)
        .exec(http("request_12")
        .post("/bei010Web/Security")
        .headers(headers_12)
        //.body(RawFileBody("SearchAccountNumberxxx_0012_request.txt"))
        .body(StringBody("""<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-
        ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <tns:authenticateUser 
      xmlns:tns="http://webservice.bei.inffinix.com/">
    <login>${Username}</login>
    <password>${pass}</password>
    <program>1</program>
   </tns:authenticateUser>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"""))

        check(regex("""errors""").count.is(0)))




}
```

Comment: It's not clear, because the second file does not have as many closing as opening braces: is the object `IC6SaaS` part of the `IC6SaaSRestUAT_Tuves` class?

Comment: Yes the object is part of IC6SaaSRestUAT_tuves.class,

Comment: What is the reason for two classes .. one scenario should have one class ..you can modularize your code ..